# Group users by age for a range

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have some data which i need to make some statistics. I need to group the users by age.

```
var byAge = displayResult.GroupBy(x => x.Age);
```

Which i can do as above. However, this gives me ages like 19, 20, 21 etc. what I want is grouping age by 10 years, such as

users between 10-20 yearsold, 20-30 years old, 30-40 years old etc.

How can i get that?

Comment: Those ages overlap (at 10, 20, 30, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can truncate the trailing digit by dividing by ten using integer division, and then multiplying back by ten.

```
 var byAge = displayResult.GroupBy(x => 10*(x.Age/10));
```

Everyone between 0, inclusive, and 10, exclusive, will be in the bucket 0.
from 10 to 20 will be under the key `10`, from 20 to 30 - under the key `20`, and so on.

Comment: The division alone would be sufficient.

Comment: @JeffMercado Sure, but then the key of the group would need to be multiplied back by ten to find out the range to which the original age belonged. I thought it would be more intuitive to multiply the key back by ten before grouping.

Comment: Ah right, I was more concerned with the grouping than I was about the key.